# Unable to load Google Colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I went to [Colaboratory!](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb) and signed in using my gmail address. I'm using Chrome. I disabled the ad blocker for Colab. When I attempt to create a new notebook I get the following error:

```
Error
Unable to load Colaboratory.
Invalid Credentials
GapiError: Invalid Credentials
    at WG.ty [as constructor] (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190326-125300-RC00_240408695:1346:363)
    at new WG (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190326-125300-RC00_240408695:1565:363)
    at Aa.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190326-125300-RC00_240408695:1654:331)
    at Ca (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190326-125300-RC00_240408695:509:336)
    at Aa.throw_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190326-125300-RC00_240408695:508:402)
    at Ea.throw (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190326-125300-RC00_240408695:510:248)
    at c (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190326-125300-RC00_240408695:519:79)
```

I am at work using their proxy/firewall. Might I need to change proxy settings?